# Appcelerator enforcing Javascript strict mode when building for iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm new to the Appcelerator environment and inheriting an existing application.

I've got the code running in the iPhone simulator, but when I try to build to deploy to an iPhone I see the following error during compile:

[ERROR] :  /Users/user/PetTrax/appcelerator/pettrax_mobile_app/Resources/iphone/html/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js: Deleting local variable in strict mode (6705:40)

Fusioncharts is a third-party library included by the previous developer, and from the error I'm assuming that it is not compliment with javascript strict mode.

However, the application worked previously, so I can only assume that the version of Appcelerator I'm using is enforcing strict mode while a previous version did not, but I can't find any information about this, or if it is possible to disable it.  All I can find is this ticket, which seems to suggest that it *shouldn't* enforce strict mode.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1263

I also did a search of the app code base to see if there's a "use strict" anywhere, there were no matches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, could you specify the version of the titanium SDK and version of the module `fusioncharts`.

Comment: Thanks @A.A.Sebastian...

Comment: It was version 6.1.0.GA of the SDK, and I've since discovered that downgrading to 6.0.4.GA resolves the issue.  It's version 3.6.0 of fusioncharts... thanks @A.A.Sebastian